# AWS IAM: How to grant access for certain user to certain dynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Situation:
user_1
user_2
dynamodb_1
dynamodb_2

Problematic:
I need my **user_1** to only get access of the **dynamodb_1** and the **user_2** the **dynamodb_2**.

Possibilities:
AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess
AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole
AWSLambdaInvocation-DynamoDB

But if I give **AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess** to the users, they can access both...
I'm afraid that someone use this access to steal or suppress everything (because he can now with the secured_key written on the code if he get the app files).
A solution would be to put the secured_key into a lambda and wait for the user to send us a request but it may be longer and be more difficult.

Or is this the good way to do secured dynamoDB ? Passing in a lambda ?

Comment: Are you looking for this? 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_specific-table.html

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I needed ! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a policy that only enables actions on DynamoDB tables with the provided name. More details :  [Allows access to a specific table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_specific-table.html)